# Android getting lag on large directory (10k+ subfiles) in custom file explorer

Tags: android, file, user-interface, lag

I am developing an android file explorer based on this open source one: https://github.com/DF1E/SimpleExplorer

Basically I added some custom viewer classes but the browser itself is untouched. My problem is, that when I scroll over a directory that has 10k+ subfiles, I notice a big lag on UI and choreographer tells me it skips frames. No big issue in Ram or anywhere else. Please help me with this. Here is the code for adapter:

```
public class BrowserListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final Resources mResources;
private ArrayList<String> mDataSource;
private final Context mContext;

public BrowserListAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    mInflater = inflater;
    mContext = context;
    mDataSource = new ArrayList<>();
    mResources = context.getResources();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    int num_items = 0;
    final File file = new File(getItem(position));
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
            DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_browserlist, parent,
                false);
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (Settings.getListAppearance() > 0) {
        mViewHolder.dateview.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mViewHolder.dateview.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }

    // get icon
    IconPreview.getFileIcon(file, mViewHolder.icon);
    if (Settings.getListAppearance() > 0) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            // Shows the size of File
            mViewHolder.bottomView.setText(SimpleUtils.formatCalculatedSize(file.length()));
        } else {
            String[] list = file.list();

            if (list != null)
                num_items = list.length;

            // show the number of files in Folder
            mViewHolder.bottomView.setText(num_items
                    + mResources.getString(R.string.files));
        }
    }

    mViewHolder.topView.setText(file.getName());
    mViewHolder.dateview.setText(df.format(file.lastModified()));

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    final TextView topView;
    final TextView bottomView;
    final TextView dateview;
    final ImageView icon;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        topView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.top_view);
        bottomView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_view);
        dateview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateview);
        icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
    }
}

public void addFiles(String path) {
    if (!mDataSource.isEmpty())
        mDataSource.clear();

    mDataSource = SimpleUtils.listFiles(path, mContext);

    // sort files with a comparator if not empty
    if (!mDataSource.isEmpty())
        SortUtils.sortList(mDataSource, path);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addContent(ArrayList<String> files) {
    if (!mDataSource.isEmpty())
        mDataSource.clear();

    mDataSource = files;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getPosition(String path) {
    return mDataSource.indexOf(path);
}

public ArrayList<String> getContent() {
    return mDataSource;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int pos) {
    return mDataSource.get(pos);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataSource.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your problem lies.

Comment: Hi, I tried but I only got some info about classes that were used. But as it is a lisView that always calls a lot of methods it's somehow difficult to know which method causes it. Can you please provide some info how to know what causes it ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the main lag source is how the "File" object is used. Every time, every view is creating, you are trying to file.isFile(), file.length(), or even file.list() which is forces file system to scan entire directories.
In addition that's all creates a lot of unused object that will be garbage collected too often, that requires a lot of time too.

Also every time you are creating *new File* and call DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance which also creates new instance each time.

My suggested solution is to read whole the information about all the files and store it in array.

I.e. introduce some inner class:

```
class FileInfo {
   String mName;
   boolean mIsFile;
   long mLength; // let it be number of bytes or directory files, depended on the mIsFile value
   String mLastModified; // store formatted string;
   ImageView mIcon; // cache icon as well;
}
```

then, instead of declaring ArrayList as data source make somehting like this:

```
ArrayList<FileInfo> mDataSource;
DateFormat mDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
        DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault()); // one instance, no needed to be recreated each time

...

public void addFiles(String path) {
    if (!mDataSource.isEmpty())
        mDataSource.clear();

    boolean showhidden = Settings.showHiddenFiles();

    final File file = new File(path);

    // based on source from SimpleUtils
    if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
        File[] list = file.listFile(); //get list of File object, rather than list of String

        // add files/folder to ArrayList depending on hidden status
        for (File aList : list) {
            String fileName = aList.getName();
            boolean isFile = aList.isFile();
            boolean isDir = aList.isDirectory();
            if ((isFile || isDir) && (showhidden || (fileName.charAt(0) != '.'))) {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
                fileInfo.mName = fileName;
                fileInfo.mIsFile = isFile;
                if (isFile) {
                    fileInfo.mLength = aList.length();
                } else {
                    fileInfo.mLength = aList.list().length;
                }
                fileInfo.mLastModified = mDateFormat.format(aList.lastModified());
                IconPreview.getFileIcon(aList, fileInfo.mIcon);
                mDataSource.add(fileInfo);
            }
        }
    } else if (Settings.rootAccess()) {
        //TODO make the same for root access
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.cantreadfolder), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // sort files with a comparator if not empty
    if (!mDataSource.isEmpty()) {
        Collections.sort(mDataSource, new Comparator<FileInfo>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(FileInfo lhs, FileInfo rhs) {
                return lhs.mName.toLowerCase().compareTo(rhs.mName.toLowerCase());
            }
        });
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    int num_items = 0;
    final FileInfo file = mDataSource.get(position);
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
            DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_browserlist, parent,
                false);
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (Settings.getListAppearance() > 0) {
        mViewHolder.dateview.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mViewHolder.dateview.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }

    if (Settings.getListAppearance() > 0) {
        if (file.mIsFile)) {
            // Shows the size of File
            mViewHolder.bottomView.setText(SimpleUtils.formatCalculatedSize(file.mLength));
        } else {
            // show the number of files in Folder
            mViewHolder.bottomView.setText(file.mLength
                    + mResources.getString(R.string.files));
        }
    }

    mViewHolder.topView.setText(file.mName);
    mViewHolder.dateview.setText(file.mLastModified);

    return convertView;
}
```

For further improvement you can move filling of the list into separated thread, or fill information for each item when it is displayed first time.